# Textbox not getting cleared in JQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have script for onchange of radiobutton list

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('input[type="radio"]').click(function () {
            if ($(this).attr("value") == "Yes") {
                $(".parts").show();
                ValidatorEnable($("[id$=reqPartsName]")[0], true);
                ValidatorEnable($("[id$=reqInvoice]")[0], true);
            }
            else if ($(this).attr("value") == "No") {
                **$('#txtPartsName').val('');**
                $(".parts").hide();
                ValidatorEnable($("[id$=reqPartsName]")[0], false);
                ValidatorEnable($("[id$=reqInvoice]")[0], false);
            }

        });
    });
</script>
```

I am hiding/showing a table row and enabling/disabling a validator.
All this works, except clearing a textBox.
I want to clear the textBox(txtPartsName) when radiobutton value is No.

Can anyone help me doing this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: is the textbox is asp.net control? if so you can try `$('#'+'<%=txtPartsName.ClientID%>').val('');`

Comment: are there multiple radio button on the page?

Comment: as you tagged `asp.net` to this question, my suggestion would be `$('#' + '<%= txtPartsName.ClientID %>').val("");`

Comment: have you tried this? `$('#doc_title').val("");` double qoutes in val?

Comment: Yes. That Worked for me. Thanks  Mohit and Amit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following code to clear the text box value,
because while rendering the textbox with runat tag has different value

```
$('#<%=txtPartsName.ClientID%>').val('');
```

you can use `$('#txtPartsName').val('');`if you set the following property in the textbox

```
ClientIDMode="Static"
```